# Uniformly convergence implies convergence is $ L^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

Assume we have a sequence of functions $ \left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty} $ and a function $ f $ such that $$ \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_{n}\left(t\right)|^{2}dt<\infty $$ for any $ n $ , and $$ \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f\left(t\right)|^{2}dt<\infty $$Assume in addition that $ f_n\to f $ Uniformly in $ \mathbb{R} $.

How can I prove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_{n}\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|^{2}dt=0 $ ?

For finite bounded interval this is easy, but I cannot repeat the proof that works for bounded intervals in this case, because in bounderies of the integral are $ - \infty $ and $ \infty $.

For bounded interval, say $[a,b]$, I'd write:

$$ \intop_{a}^{b}|f_{n}\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|^{2}dt\leq\intop_{a}^{b}\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f_{n}\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|^{2}dt=|b-a|\cdot\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f_{n}\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|^{2} $$

And now $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}|b-a|\cdot\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f_{n}\left(t\right)-f\left(t\right)|^{2}=0 $$

I cannot repeat this proof because an integral with bounderies $ -\infty $ and $\infty $ over a constant would diverge.

So How can I prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your proof for a bounded interval?

Comment: @IgorRivin I edit the post with the proof for bounded interval

Comment: "Assume in addition that $ f_n\to f $ Absolutely in $ \mathbb{R} $." What does that mean?

Comment: @zhw. Im sorry. I ment uniformly, editing.

Answer (score 1):

No, the result fails. Let $f_n=n^{-1/2}\chi_{[0,n]}.$ Then $f_n\in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$ for all $n.$ Let $f\equiv 0.$ Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly. But

$$\int_{\mathbb R} |f_n-f|^2 = \int_0^n (1/n) = 1$$

for all $n.$